# In CSS how do I affect links of only 1 class

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

I have a CSS and it displays fine however I want .bottom and .navt to have a link color of white and to remain white even after someone visits them. Here is my current code:

```
.toper{
border:1px solid black;
background:blue;
width:500;
height:90;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:50px;


}
.navt{
border:1px solid black;
background:darkblue;
width:1000px;
height:55px;
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
top:95px;
left:50px;
}


.bottom {
align:bottom;
border:1px solid black;
background:darkblue;
width:1000px;
height:55px;
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
left:50px;

}

body{
background:lightblue
}
```

How would I do this by just using this sheet. (I don't want to use more divs and other stuff because that would involve editing many pages whereas doing something to this page changes them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could target them like so:

```
.bottom a:link, .bottom a:visited, .navt a:link, .navt a:visited{
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.bottom a, .navt a, .bottom a:visited, .navt a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

Any link contained in elements with class `bottom` or `navt`, either visited and unvisited, will now be white.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bottom a, .navt a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

This works as so:

```
Any <a> tag in class bottom and navt, should have a foreground color of RGB Hex #fff
```

Don't worry about `hover` or `visited` yet. Unless these properties are defined, you're browser won't assume them, since you have specifically overridden assumed value for `a` itself.

Comment: That's incorrect - that targets the "bottom" class, and then links within the "navt" class, not links within both.